# Solr "function query" object: is it generated per query or per query/document?

Tags: solr

I am wondering whether a solr function query object is created per incoming query or per incoming query plus a document? My main interest is whether it makes sense to create a hashmap or something inside the function query object. If the query object is created per query/document, then my idea wouldn't make any sense. Any pointer would be appreciated as well.

Comment: i just delete my old answer, since you change the question